# Strange small bars in a mosaic plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset:

```
Category <- c("Bankpass", "Bankpass", "Bankpass", "Moving", "Moving")
Subcategory <- c("Stolen", "Lost", "Login", "Address", "New contract")
Weight <- c(10,20,13,40,20)
Duration <- as.character(c(0.2,0.4,0.5,0.44,0.66))
df <- data.frame(Category, Subcategory, Weight, Duration)
```

I use that to create the following plot:

```
#install.packages("ggmosaic")
ggplot(data = df) +
 geom_mosaic(aes(weight = Weight, x = product(Category), fill=Duration), 
 na.rm=TRUE) +    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-25, hjust= .1))
```

This works however, I see small slices in the bar that dont make sense.

[image]

Any thoughts on how I can get rid of them?

Comment: `Duration` is too long, could you check this and edit?

Comment: @Tino, did it. Sorry

Comment: Still not reproducible. What is `df2`? I get `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`.

Comment: Anyway somthing wrong with your code, you call `ggplot` on `df2`. What is this object? a transformation of `df`?

Comment: Sorry again guys, small typo. Should be reproducible now!

Comment: @HenkStraten, looks like you have not updated the code as yet. For, I get the same error message as stated by Tino, "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

Comment: I was reading the data from a .csv and there the format was off. Should be fine now

Comment: There is somthing weird with your plot and data. 
Duration has 5 levels, while in your plot I may see only four...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside `geom_mosaic`add `offset = 0`.

```
ggplot(data = df) +
 geom_mosaic(aes(weight = Weight, x = product(Category), fill=Duration), 
 offset = 0, na.rm=TRUE) +  
 theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-25, hjust= .1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I see small slices in the bar that dont make sense.

It appears that the geom_mosaic call is plotting all levels of Subcategory for both Categories. Many would consider this to be a "feature" and not a "bug." See the plot below, which uses your exact call, but uses `fill = Subcategory`[image]

You can also see this by using the command `table(df$Category, df$Subcategory)` which shows

> ```
>          Address Login Lost New contract Stolen
> Bankpass       0     1    1            0      1
> Moving         1     0    0            1      0
> ```

In any event, the easiest solution is the one mentioned by @esm above, use `offset = 0` to hide these factors which have no entries.